# Read URL from a Java program

Tags: java, web-applications, url

I have been trying to read content of a weblink of

http://chennai.click.in/classified/real-estate/land-plots/residential-land-for-sale-sriperumbudur-1842564.html

But I am not able to read the content through the Object URL.
It is reading some other link and printing it on console.

I want to save the HTML sourcecode of this link in some file..
Can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: The authors of this page don't want a spider to read the content. Please read their terms of use.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Restricted activity](http://chennai.click.in/termsandconditions.html#terms14) section in the Terms & Conditions.

> Use robot, spider, scraper or other
>   automated means to access the Site 
>   for any purpose without our express
>   written permission is prohibited.

Comment: if you only want the source ... just right click your browser and select 'view source' or use a tool like firebug to show you the live document structure